# How to sum 2 DecimalFields in a model and display in admin view?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 DecimalFields in 1 model.
How can I sum both fields together and have the total show up in the admin view?

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
spotters = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=150)
```

There has to be a "container to retain the sum in admin view so I have:

```
total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=3, default=0)
```

At the end.

Then I finish with a return method:

```
def get_cost(self):
    return self.price + self.spotters
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to work with a property and *without* a `total_price`, since that only introduces *data duplication*, so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    spotters = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=150)

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        return self.price + self.spotter
```

In the `ModelAdmin`, you can then add `'total_price'` in the [**`readonly_fields`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('price', 'spotters', 'total_price')
    fields = ('price', 'spotters')
    readonly_fields = ('total_price',)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks William, I tried your answer but the total cost is not in view in the admin environment

Comment: class ServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'category',
        'name',
        'includes',
        'description',
        'price',
        'spotters',
    )
    readonlyfields = ('get_cost',)

Comment: the total_price field is visible but it does not carryout the sum

Comment: @Rp_Web: IT's not `get_cost`, but `total_price`.

Comment: apologies William. I changes that also and still doesn't work.... @property
    def total_price(self):
        return self.price + self.spotter

Comment: readonly_fields = ('total_price',) I can see the readonly_field when creating a service but it doesn't sum the total and I do not see the total_price field in the main admin view

Comment: @Rp_Web: what if you add it to the `list_display` as well?

Comment: I did that also :) its all working now William. I had a spelling error lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list display of `ModelAdmin` as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_cost(self) -> int:
        return self.price + self.spotters

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['get_cost']
```

Comment: oh... hangon guys... its all working now... I had a grammatical error. thanks to all for the support. brilliant!!!